# How to remove items from a list on the SAME INDEX of duplicates i removed from another list

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have two lists of items, one for avatar names, and one for avatar pictures:

```
name_list = ['name1', 'name2', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5', 'name5']
picture_list = ['pic1', 'pic2', 'pic3', 'pic4', 'pic5', 'pic6', 'pic7']
```

I need each item from the name_list to always stay on the same index it shares with the item in the picture_list. So that when I remove the duplicates from the name_list, the items in the picture_list will be removed accordingly. So that the result is:

```
name_list = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5']
picture_list = ['pic1', 'pic2', 'pic4', 'pic5', 'pic6']
```

(It's important to mention that the numbers of the picture and the name don't have to be the same. only that they'll stay on the same index they shared before)

How may I do so in code?

Comment: How do you know that `pic2` is not the right value, and `pic3` should be removed instead?

Comment: I know there's a simple code for removing duplicates. I just wonder if there's a variation for two lists. Since I don't want waste time on going over it each duplicate index by duplicate index.

Comment: @Selenium_for_life For `name2`, how do you determine which of the pic records to delete? For name5, how do you know which to keep?

Comment: Use a dictionary: Name as key, picture as value - or zip both list together to tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using nested lists. Consider the following:

```py
item_lists = [
    ['name1', 'pic1'],
    ['name2', 'pic2'],
    # etc.
]

del item_lists[1]
```

This way you always keep the name and pictures together, and delete them simultaneously.